# Stop Dropbox from syncing on WiFi

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dropbox

How do I make Dropbox on Linux only sync over Ethernet? My WiFi card is rather malfunction-y, and Dropbox "sputters" when on WiFi and eats up my processor (this is definitely a driver issue, not a Dropbox issue). I'm on Arch Linux with kernel `3.11.1-2-ARCH`, with GNOME 3 and NetworkManager. I know that if I used netctl this would be easy, but I'm usually moving between WiFi networks and NetworkManager seems to work best with this and GNOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArchLinux allows you to change how Dropbox is running based on how you are connecting to the Internet.
I would take a look here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox#Dropbox_on_laptops

This will allow you to disable/enable Dropbox based on what interface you are using.

Edit:
To do this via networkmanager you can use the dispatcher script method described.

Answer (score 1):

Add a a new route in your routing table, over dev wlan0, instructing it to use localhost as the gateway for the dropbox IP addresses. But, I repeat, only over dev wlan0.

Comment: This wouldn't keep Dropbox from actually running. It just wouldn't let it connect to the Dropbox server.

Comment: True, which is exactly what was being asked: tikking did not want to use netctl, the solution your reference points to. I am on Arch too...